# Unclear #define syntax in cpp using `\` sign

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

```
#define  is_module_error(_module_,_error_)    \
   ((_module_##_errors<_error_)&&(_error_<_module_##_errors_end))

#define  is_general_error(_error_)     is_module_error(general,_error_)
#define  is_network_error(_error_)     is_module_error(network,_error_)
```

Can someone please explain to me what does the first define means?

How is is evaluated?

I don't understand what's the `\` sign mean here?

Comment: It just continuates the line (escapes the return). `#define` must declare the macro with in a single line.

Comment: Note that it's actually a `\` followed by the end of the line; if there's any other character after it (including a space) you've got an  ordinary escape sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash is the line continuation symbol used in preprocessor directives. It tells the preprocessor to merge the following line with the current one. In other words it escapes the hard newline at the end of the line.

In the specific example, it tells the preprocessor that

```
#define  is_module_error(_module_,_error_)    \
   ((_module_##_errors<_error_)&&(_error_<_module_##_errors_end))
```

should be interpreted as:

```
#define  is_module_error(_module_,_error_)  ((_module_##_errors<_error_)&&(_error_<_module_##_errors_end))
```

The relevant quote from the C99 draft standard (N1256) is the following:

> #### 6.10 Preprocessing directives
>
> [...]
>
> **Description**
>
> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the
>   following constraints: The first token in the sequence is a `#` preprocessing token that (at
>   the start of translation phase 4) is either the first character in the source file (optionally
>   after white space containing no new-line characters) or that follows white space
>   containing at least one new-line character. ***The last token in the sequence is the first new-line character that follows the first token in the sequence.*** A new-line character ends
>   the preprocessing directive even if it occurs within what would otherwise be an invocation of a function-like macro.

Emphasis on the relevant sentence is mine.

If you are also unsure of what the `##` symbol means, it is the **token-pasting operator**. From the already cited C99 document (emphasis mine):

> #### 6.10.3.3 The ## operator
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> ***If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
>   or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument’s preprocessing token sequence***; however, if an argument consists of no preprocessing tokens, the parameter is replaced by a placemarker preprocessing token instead.

In the case at hand this means that, for example, wherever the preprocessor finds the following macro "call":

```
is_module_error(dangerous_module,blow_up_error)
```

it will replace it with this code fragment:

```
((dangerous_module_errors<blow_up_error)&&(blow_up_error<dangerous_module_errors_end))
```

Comment: Second sentence, "compiler" should be "preprocessor". This is over and done with long before the compiler gets it mitts on the translation unit.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The preprocessor is part of the compiler. "Compiler" is an overloaded term, and I don't see how trying to pick a single nit makes anything clearer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, right. I was thinking of preprocessing as the first phase of compilation, but this is not precise. I'm going to edit that. Thanks.

Comment: @GManNickG I can only disagree, and go into that good night. And I wasn't nit-picking the poster (in fact I upvoted him already) He states in the second paragraph the correct term, and I was only pointing to the inconsistency. If that offended you in some way, I sincerely apologize.

Comment: @GManNickG you're right that the term Compiler is overloaded however as computer scientists we operate in a realm of precision, and the term "compiler" when "preprocessor" is meant is imprecise and inaccurate. If you already understand the difference and are personally ok with the overload that's fine, however muddling the differences on a forum intended to teach other people does them a disservice and WhozCraig is, in my opinion, right to point out the difference.